# Displaying and Uploading Image with php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I am trying to display images that I have uploaded to my MySQL database.
The uploading process is working properly, but I have issues in displaying from it and I don't know where I am going wrong.

This is my DB:

```
 CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dozent` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `datum` date NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `Ort` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gastvortraege` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `src` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The data I upload is inserted with this code:

```
require("vortraege_db.php");

$stmt = $con->stmt_init();

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['titel']);
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['text']);
$ort = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST ['ort']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['datum']);

$path = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(isset($_POST['gast']))
    $uniname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['gast_text']);
else {
    $uniname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,'');
}

$image = file_get_contents($path);
$image = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $image);


$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO data(dozent,datum,`text`,Ort,gastvortraege,src) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssb',$name,$date,$text,$ort,$uniname,$image);
$result = $stmt->execute();

if($result)
    echo "Datensätze erfolgreich hochgeladen";
else {
    echo "Es ist irgendwas schiefgelaufen, bitte erneut versuchen.";
}
```

Just for testing purpose I used many code snippets I found on stackoverflow, that was the latest one:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `data`";
$sth = $con->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['src'] ).'"/>';
```

With all of the code I tried I got the same result: a white page.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`. Also, how are you assuming that the blob is a `jpg` and not a gif/png or something else. Are you allowing only `jpg` file uploads?

Comment: Thank you :)
Im assuming that blob is jpg because its just for testing and i only upload jpg files, so i dont need to check if there are other file formats.
Edit: its the same result when I use  `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Ok, does `mysqli_fetch_assoc` work? Your query will return multiple records from the database, so you will have to read them one by one or change your query to read only the record that you want.

Comment: Unfortunately not I tried also this: 
`while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($r['src']).'">';
}`

Comment: What does your error log show? You shouldn't escape with parameterized queries.

Comment: Can you print the value of the array `$r`?

Comment: My error log is showing nothing relevant, 
Result of printing $r: 
`Array ( [id] => 1 [dozent] => Test [datum] => 2018-01-13 [text] => testtext [Ort] => Testort [gastvortraege] => [src] => `

Comment: `src` is blank as per your result, that's why the image is not showing anything? Are you sure there is any data in the record with the `id=1`?

Comment: Yes there is data saved as you can see here:
[link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkWGue37IBwri94xJgXIRvkgyX-auQ)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change this line:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['src'] ).'"/>';
```

To this:

```
foreach($result as $r){
  echo "<img src='".$r['src']."' />";
}
```